# how to make a image that exist of several parts as a background image

Tags: css, image

I have to make several pages in html. 
I know the x and Y coordinate of each part.

So some images exist of a 5 * 4 grid and some of them exist of a  4 * 5 grid. 
Is there a way I can make this image filling the whole browser and as background.

I thought myself of using a table.  But both sort images does not fitt into 1 sort of table.

I make this project in rails 4

How can I still achieve what I want ?

Edit 1 :

My html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Images</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                       'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
  </script>
<![endif]-->     
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <main role="main">
            <section>
                <article id="images">
              </article>
           </section>
       </main>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

style.css :

```
body {

}
/* Default link styling */
a:link { color:#0271fb; }
a:visited { color:#bd02fb; }
a:hover, a:focus { color:#000; }
a:active { color:#fb0e02; }


body {
}

@media print {
    * {
        color:#000 !important;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        text-shadow:none !important;
        background:transparent !important;
    }
    html { background-color:#fff; }

    nav { display:none; }

    a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ") "; }
    a[href] {
       font-weight:bold;
       text-decoration:underline;
        color:#06c;
        border:none;
    }
   a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content:""; }

   abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }

   figure { 
       margin-bottom:1em; 
       overflow:hidden;
   }

   figure img { border:1px solid #000; }
}
```

I do not have more because im still puzzling how to solve this

Comment: Could you please post your current HTML and CSS

Comment: Cutting an image in small parts and loading each separately is considered bad practice and should be avoided. It is better to load all the image in one go and display it as background of a container element. This way you avoid having some parts of the image loaded and also you replace several calls for resources with only one request. (You can't download more than 5 resources at once from the same domain) so cutting an image in 20 parts will inevitably result in chunky loading.

Comment: I understand but I have to pull the images of a external api that  give a response  with several url's where I can download the parts

Comment: could always use a [`<map>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-map-element) [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).  *(i say this with moderate sarcasm, as image maps aren't a great practice as @AndreiGheorghiu has pointed out.)*